How to show that a Martingale converges almost sure?
This is a follow up question to Show that $Y_n:=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a Martingale..
I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $(X_n)_n$ be independent and identical distributed random
variables that are uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$. Define
$Y_n:=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$. Show that $(Y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ convreges almost sure to a random variable $Y$.

Apporach:
By Definition the PDF of $X_i$ is
$f_{X_i}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{1}{2},&x\in [0,2]\\0,&x\not\in[0,2]\end{array}\right.$
and so $f_{Y_n}(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n f_{X_i}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{1}{2^n},&x\in [0,2]\\0,&x\not\in[0,2]\end{array}\right.$.
To show that $(Y_n)$ converges a.s. I want to use the following convergence theorem:
Let $(M_n)_n$ be a uniformly integrable Martingale. Then $M_{\infty}:=lim M_n$ exists almost sure (and in $L^1$).
As far as I know, one easy condition for uniformly integrable is that there exists a random variable $Z$ s.t. $E[Z]<\infty$ and $Z \geq |M_n|$ for all $n$.
In this case we could choose $Z=1 \chi_{[0,2]}$, then $E[Z]=2$ and $Z \geq |Y_n|$ for every $n$, since $1 \geq (1/2)^n$.
Is this correct?

Note that the density of the product of two random variables is not the product of their densities. Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables

@Maxi How do I then show a.s. convergence? There is no way I could do this integral for $n$ random variables.

Maybe try considering $ln(Y_n)=ln(X_1...X_n)=ln(X_1)+...+ln(X_n)=n \cdot ln(X_1)$

Any non-negative martingale converges almost surely. Ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems

@Maxi How should one use this? I have to show that for every $\epsilon >0 : P(lim|Y_n-Y|<\epsilon)=1$

@geetha290krm But isn't that only for supermartingals?

Every martingale is a  super-(as well as  sub-) martingale.

@geetha290krm Oh, yeah right!  In that case, for fixed $n \in \mathbb{n}: E[Y_n]=nE[X_i] < \infty$, and by doobs convergence theorem $Y_n$ converges to some $Y$ a.s. . Is this correct?

Yes, that is correct.

@geetha290krm Thank you very much!

Actually, $EY_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n} EX_i=1$

This martingale is not uniformly integrable, but it is $L^1$-bounded, because it's nonnegative. Do you know a version of the Martingale Convergence Theorem for $L^1$-bounded martingales?
